# mouseleave not turned back on again

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseleave

I'm trying to create a button that increases in size when the mouse is on it and then stays that size when it's clicked. Whenever another button is clicked it will shrink again and the second button will increase in size. In my current code I want to try to turn off the shrinking when it's clicked by adding an .off(mouseleave) and adding an .on(mouseleave) when another button is clicked, however when I click another button the 'mouseleave' isn't turned back on again. Anyone got a clue what might be the problem?

$("p.growth").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            "font-size":"30px"
        })
        });

```
    $("p.growth").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        "font-size":"24px"
    })
    });


$("p#past").click(function(){
    $(this).off("mouseleave");
    $("p#present").on("mouseleave"); 
    $("p#future").on("mouseleave");

            $("p#present").animate({
        "font-size":"24px"
    })
    $("p#future").animate({
        "font-size":"24px"
    })

});
$("p#present").click(function(){
    $(this).off("mouseleave");
            $("p#past").on("mouseleave");
    $("p#future").on("mouseleave");

    $("p#past").animate({
        "font-size":"24px"
    })
    $("p#future").animate({
        "font-size":"24px"
    })

});
$("p#future").click(function(){
    $(this).off("mouseleave");
            $("p#present").on("mouseleave");
    $("p#past").on("mouseleave");

    $("p#present").animate({
        "font-size":"24px"
    })
    $("p#past").animate({
        "font-size":"24px"
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) instead of using [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) and [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) **again and again**

Comment: The animations should be stopped until the next button is clicked, how do I do this with the stop() event?